# SLAB memory management

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm confused as to the structuring of the [SLAB memory management mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation).

I get that there are multiple 'caches' that are specific to commonly used data objects, but why does each cache contain multiple 'slabs'?

What differentiates each slab within a cache? Why not simply have the cache filled with the data objects themselves? Why does there need to be this extra layer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The slab allocator is an abstraction layer to make easier allocation of numerous objects of a same type. 
The interface offers the function

```c
struct kmem_cache * kmem_cache_create(const char *name,
    size_t size, size_t align, unsigned long flags,
    void (*ctor)(void*));
```

This function creates a new slab allocator that will be able to handle allocation of `size`-bytes long objects. If the creation is successful, you get your pointer to the related `struct kmem_cache`. This structures holds information about the *slabs* it manages.

As it is implied on the Wikipedia description, the purpose of such an extra layer is to prevent memory fragmentation issues that could happen if the memory allocation was made in a simple and intuitive manner. To do so, it introduces the notion of *slab* through the following data structure :

```c
struct slab {
    struct list_head list; /* embedded list structure */
    unsigned long colouroff;
    void *s_mem; /* first object in the slab */
    unsigned int inuse; /* allocated objects in the slab */
    kmem_bufctl_t free; /* first free object (if any) */
};
```

Thus, the `kmem_cache` object holds 3 lists of its *slabs*, gathered in 3 flavours :

- Empty slabs : these slabs do not contain an in-use object.
- Partial slabs : these slabs contain objects currently used but there is still memory area that can hold new objects.
- Full slabs : these slabs contains objects being used and cannot host new objects (full ...).

When requesting an object through the slab allocator, it will try to get the required memory area within a partial slab, if it cannot, it will get it from an empty slab.

If you are eager to collect more information about this, you should take a look at Robert Love's [*Linux Kernel Development*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468)

Answer (score 4):

I may be too late to answer this, but this may help others as well.
As I see from [Understanding Linux Virtual Memory Manager](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/pdf/understand.pdf), having slabs has three major benefits.

1. **Reducing internal fragmentation** caused by buddy system. Because we have caches that best suits smaller objects.
2. **Better hardware cache usage** - by aligining objects to start at different offsets in different slabs so that interference between cache lines can be reduced. This is based on assumption that we have physically indexed cache.
3. A slab is primary unit in cache, which is acquired/relinquished at once. This causes **reduction in external fragmentation** as well.

See section 3.2 from [The Slab Allocator: An Object Caching Kernel memory Allocator](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.29.4759) (1994).

Comment: How does is reduce internal fragmentation? Often slabs are only partially full

Comment: @Imray : Internal fragmentation occurs when the size of data is lesser than the size of block allocated to hold the data. When you allocate cache blocks of size exactly as that of cache object size "internal" fragmentation decreases automatically. Being PARTIALLY FULL was never a criteria of fragmentation.

Comment: There is a similar effect if the sum of the object sizes in a slab is less than the slab size. Consider an ext4 inode cache object, which happens (in a particular kernel) to be 1070 bytes in size. The SLAB allocator chooses a 4k slab for this, because it is marked as reclaimable. 1070 * 3 = 3210 + 886 waste bytes. A few bytes are used for internal free-lists, but over 20% of the space allocated cannot be used. Moreover, reclamation of some inodes in a slab may lead to chunks of memory which are not full, yet cannot be used for other purposes until the remaining objects in a slab are reclaimed.

Comment: Agree, however if we talk about same in other allocator, say buddy allocator, you will have fragmentation per object. In slab allocator, the fragmentation that you are talking about is utilized for a better cause like cache efficiency, which is not same in other case. Please refer **slab-colouring**.

Comment: Possible additional source https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/10184/Ghods_Amir%20Reza.pdf?sequence=3